# How can I exclude some library paths listed in " pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config"?

Tags: linux, compiling, make, libraries, pkg-config

I have Ubuntu 14.04 upgraded from 12.04 making dist-upgrades. I did many manual installations such as ffmpeg, libglib and so on, in the past. I have a nice custom distro now, it works well but I have problems while trying to compile applications. It stems from library conflicts between  manually installed packages from source code and native distro libraries. A guy advised me to rename `/usr/local` it works but boot failed on next reboot.

When I look for directories added by `pkg-config` with

```
  pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

it lists

```
 /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

I don't want it to look for paths in `/usr/local/lib...`

How can I ban those paths not to let `pkg-config` look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuff in `/usr/local` usually supersedes stuff in `/usr`, so I'm a bit confused as to why you would install libraries there to have a "a nice custom distro", but then not want to compile against them.  Those are the libraries the system will use actually use.

Anyway, `man pkg-config` claims the base search path:

> is libdir/pkgconfig:datadir/pkgconfig where *libdir* is the libdir for pkg-config  and  *datadir*  is
>                 the datadir for pkg-config **when it was installed.**

This implies they are compiled in.  I notice it is different on ubuntu than fedora -- the former is long and inclusive, whereas the latter is short and exclusive; on fedora I have to set a `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to include `/usr/local`.

Since paths in `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` are checked *first*, you could just set:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

The fact that these are at the end of the built-in paths won't matter; if the check makes it to there without finding anything, there's nothing to be found.

---

To demonstrate how this works, create a temporary directory `/opt/bs/pkg` and copy a `.pc` file from one of the directories in the default path into it -- e.g., `alsa.pc`.  First check;

```
> pkg-config --libs alsa
-lasound
```

Now go into `/opt/bs/pkg/alsa.pc` and change `-lasound` (it's in the `Libs:` field) to `-foobar`.  Set `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and try again:

```
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/bs/pkg pkg-config --libs alsa
-foobar
```

Eureka, `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` has overridden the built-in paths...you can delete `/opt/bs/pkg`, of course.

Comment: I actually tried `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig` beforehand but it didn't work. after setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` still `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` prints `usr/local`

Comment: Right -- you haven't changed the default path, but paths in `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` are checked first.  After you set it, you can check by calling, e.g. `pkg-config --libs somepackage` where "somepackage" has a `.pc` file in multiple places.

Comment: manpage says `pkg-config  retrieves  information  about  packages  from special metadata files. These files are named
       after the package, and has a .pc extension.  On most systems, pkg-config looks  in  /usr/lib/pkgconfig,
       /usr/share/pkgconfig, /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig and /usr/local/share/pkgconfig for these files.  It will
       additionally look in the colon-separated (on Windows, semicolon-separated) list of  directories  speci‐
       fied by the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.` so isn't there any way to exclude `/usr/local/share/pkgconfig` ?

Comment: No, but it doesn't matter if you prioritize the paths you want to prioritize.  I've added an example of what I'm talking about to demonstrate that **using $PKG_CONFIG_PATH works.**

Comment: let me test your method again, I got library error while compiling this https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr.git I hope it works, I believe I tried your method and it didn't work

Comment: It works to do what you've asked for in the question, so if you use it properly and have errors compiling something, the problem isn't to do with what you've asked about.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It's permissive and allows looking for libraries in `usr/local/...`  I think only way to achieve what I want is to rename pkgconfig directories in `usr/local` as a workaround

Comment: Okay, but *the only way it will find those is if the libraries are not installed anywhere else.*  In this case your choices are: 1) Use version from `/usr/local`. 2) Do not use the library at all, in which case, if they are required, `./configure` will bail out.  If it's choosing a `.pc` file from `/usr/local` when there is one in `/usr`  **then you did not export $PKG_CONFIG_PATH properly**.  End of story.  There is no ambiguity about this.